# Issue Deploying Nuxt.js Project on Vercel - Missing "dist" Directory

Tags: vue.js, deployment, nuxt.js, vercel

I'm encountering an issue while trying to deploy my Nuxt.js project on Vercel. The deployment process fails, and I'm getting the error message "No Output Directory named 'dist' found after the Build completed."

Problem Description:

I've followed the official Nuxt.js documentation and configured my project to generate the production build in the "dist" directory in my nuxt.config.js file:

```
 generate: {
    dir: 'dist',
  },
  build: {
    // dir: 'dist',
    aggressiveCodeRemoval: true,
    // transpile : ['vue-typical']
    // Add exception
    // build error parse
    transpile: ['vee-validate/dist/rules'],
    postcss: {
      plugins: {
        'postcss-custom-properties': false,
      },
    },
```

However, when I attempt to deploy my project on Vercel, it seems unable to locate the "dist" directory, causing the deployment to fail.

even i tried with

```
 build: {
    // dir: 'dist',}
```

too. but i got same error.
[image: this is my json file]

[image: nuxt.config.js]

i have updated my dependencies and adjust nuxt.config.js file few times.